# Select specific fields in Prisma not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I would like to select specific fields

```
return this.prisma.user.findFirst({
  where: {
    password_hash: createHash('md5')
      .update(`${userId.id}test`)
      .digest('hex'),
  },
  select: {
    name: true,
    email: true,
  },
});
```

But I'm getting this Typing error

> Type '{ name: string; email: string; }' is missing the following
> properties from type 'User': id, password_hash

Here's the type definition of the user

```
export type User = {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
  password_hash: string
}
```

Comment: What is the expected return type of the function? Because of the `select` in your query, the return expression is of type `Promise<{ name: string, email: string } | null>`. Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the wrong type in the function from which you are calling it. If you add a `select` clause, the returned result is thinned out to the properties of your select, while you pretend to return a full `User` from the wrapping function:

```
// The full user:
type User = {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
  password_hash: string
}

// Here you pretend to return a full user:
function getUser(userId): Promise<User | null> {
  return this.prisma.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      password_hash: createHash('md5')
        .update(`${userId.id}test`)
        .digest('hex'),
    },
    select: { // Here you remove some properties from the user:
      name: true,
      email: true,
    },
  });
}
```

You can fix it by changing the return type:

```
function getUser(userId): Promise<{ name: string, email: string } | null> {
   ...
}
```